# Gradle - how do I exclude a resource from the executable jar?

Tags: gradle, jar, logback

I have a "production" logback configuration file logback.xml under src/main/resources... but that directory also contains the "testing" logback configuration file logback-test.xml (which logback looks for first).

When creating an executable jar I want to delete the "testing" xml file.

I tried this

```
jar {
    manifest {
        // PS this is the correct line for Shadow Plugin...
        attributes 'Class-Path': '/libs/a.jar'
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'core.MyMainClass'
    }
    exclude("**/resources/*test*")
}
```

and I tried this

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Class-Path': '/libs/a.jar'
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'core.MyMainClass'
    }
    doLast {
        exclude("**/resources/*test*")
    }
}
```

... what am I doing wrong?

***later***

I find [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-exclude-src-main-resources-files-from-the-final-war/11895/2) that I was probably making life difficult for myself in putting these xmls under /src/main/resources ... so I created a new directory under src, /logback, and put the files in there instead.  I added this to the classpath (as logback says that's where it looks for these files) by doing this:

```
test {
    classpath += files( 'src/logback' )
}
```

Interestingly, as well as meaning that logging during testing happens OK, this is enough to get the resulting executable jar to use logback OK when run.

Unfortunately, configuring the "shadowJar" `task` like this

```
shadowJar {
     baseName = 'DocumentIndexer'
     classifier = null
     version = project.version
     exclude("logback/*test*")
}
```

or configuring "jar" `task` like this:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Class-Path': '/libs/a.jar'
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'core.ConsoleIOHandler'
    }
    exclude("logback/*test*")
}
```

... just refuses to work: the file logback-test.xml is still there in the jar.

Answer (score 0):

I got [the answer](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/exclude-resource-file-from-jar-file/21215) from the forums at gradle.org.

The basic answer is that the "test" logback config file should go under src/test/resources and the "production" config file should go under src/main/resources.  This way the former will be excluded from the jar.

The answerer also said the "resources" is one of the roots from which relative paths are specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
configurations {
    provided
    compile.extendsFrom provided
}

dependencies {
    provided 'WHATEVER' // Packages you don't need to add to jar
    provided 'Other WHATEVER' // Packages you don't need to add to jar

    shadow 'OTHER' // Packages you need to add to jar
    shadow 'Another OTHER' // Packages you need to add to jar
}

shadowJar {
    configurations = [project.configurations.shadow] // ***
}
```

as mentioned [here](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/dependencies/)

line *** is the way to tell shadow what dependencies to include in jar